# How to send double quotes in postman csv data file

Tags: data-driven, csv-file, postman

I have the following request body:

```
{

username:{{user}},
password:{{pass}}

}
```

The expected structure of the request is :

```
{

username:"something",
password:"something"

}
```

if the request body is something like, below then i have to validate that i get 400 status code :

```
{

  username:something,
  password:tes45

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is interesting,

Newman and the collection runner are behaving differently. I have raised a bug on postman for this :

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/8024#issue-562149355

So coming to your question :

To run from collection runner wrap double-quotes between double quotes:

```
user,pass
"""something""","""something"""
```

To run from newman, escape double-quotes using blackslash:

```
user,pass
"\"something\"","\"something\""           //here the outer double quotes tell the parser that its a string , and inside we write \" to escape it.
```